# Java EE CDI: Get all instances of the same interface programmatically

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, cdi

*My environment: Java EE 7, JBoss EAP 7.0.1, JDK 1.8.*

It is well known that one could retrieve all instances of the same interface using annotations as follows:

```
@Inject
private Instance<ConfigurationProvider> configurationProvider;
```

However, I need the programmatic-equivalent such that I could fetch all instances of *any* interface on-the-fly. Is there a way?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `Instance<Object>` then `select(MyInterface.class)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can either do `Instance<Object>` or `CDI.current()` to get a base instance object, then `select(SomeInterface.class)` to find that specific interface.  Or if you want to get all beans, just iterate over the objects returned from either of the first two methods.